# Right side menu button on simulator with Android skins

Tags: android, codenameone

I have created a toolbar with a rightSideMenu using the following code snippet

```
Button account = new Button("");
titleWithCommands.add(BorderLayout.EAST, FlowLayout.encloseIn(account));
account.addActionListener(e -> tb.openRightSideMenu());
```

This works fine on the simulator using iPhone skins, but when i use the Samsung skins, the menu button is unresponsive. I have built the Andoid app and installed onto an Android device (Samsung S3), and i am experiencing the same issue, the menu button is unresponsive!

With the same (similar) code as below

```
Button account = new Button("");
titleWithCommands.add(BorderLayout.WEST, FlowLayout.encloseIn(account));
account.addActionListener(e -> tb.openSideMenu());
```

It works well on both simulator and device. What am i missing?

Comment: The button has no size or content, try adding text to the button and see if it works

Comment: @Shai Almog The button has an icon on it, and upon further debugging, i discovered that actually the button is working, but for some reason, when it is positioned right in the top right corner, it is being blocked by something, which i have not been able to discover as yet. But if i move it inwards, then i am able to use it.

`Container mainToolBar = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
mainToolBar.add(titleWithCommands);
..
..
tb.setTitleComponent(mainToolBar);`

My CSS
MenuButton {
    font-size: 5mm;
    color : #ffffff;
    margin: 1mm 0mm 1mm 0mm; 
    padding: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; 
}

Comment: This might be related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954030/event-handling-anomaly