# Event handling anomaly

Tags: event-handling, codenameone

After the last library update (my jar files dates is 22. Oct.) The event handling does not work as expected. For example the SwipeEvent in SwipeableContainer and the ActionListener in FloatinAutton works. But the button and MultiButton does not. I debuged it. Does not fall into any EventDispatcher instance that includes relevant listener. So the handler code defined in the form (multiButton.addActionListener(e -> {...) is not called anymore.

This phenomenon can be reproduced by recompiling the KitchenSink app and running it in the simulator. And the downloaded apk does not work correctly. The the app can be downloaded [from here](http://s1.toldacuccot.hu/letoltes?sid=34abbec4724f4051aaa93ff8fa731614&file=KitchenSink-debug.apk)

When I copy back the earlier backup of libraries and compile the app it works in the simulator. I think the relevant component is the JavaSE.jar. Unfortunately with the old libraries can not make my application on the build server.

Best regards
Péter

Comment: Thanks for the test case, I see an issue. We'll push a fix later today

Comment: Shai when can I expect a fix for this issue? Thanks

Comment: Shai, I ran the "Update Project Libs". Some libray have been updated. Now the event handler process works. I was waiting here your feedback.