# Components are not working after doing Refresh cn1lib files

Tags: codenameone

I notice some components are broken after doing Refresh cn1lib files. Please advise if anyone else face same situation.

Comment: We'll need more details than that

Comment: App gets frozen after clicking on component in infinite container. I don't see any error in console.

Comment: Giving the build will automatically update the cn1libs ? Please advise.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the same as this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954030/event-handling-anomaly

Comment: yes Shai. correct. there could be other regressions as well.

Comment: Shai..when can i expect the fix fro this issue. Please advise.

Comment: This was pushed out yesterday night